# Finding the date one month in advance on the same day

Tags: mysql, date

In MySQL, I can do something like:

> SELECT DATE_ADD('2010-07-02', INTERVAL 1 MONTH)

And that returns:

> 2010-08-02

That's great... now is there a MySQL function that I can use to find what the date would be one month in advance on the same day.  For example, 7/2/2010 falls on the first Friday of July, 2010.  Is there an easy way to find what the first Friday of August, 2010 is with an SQL statement?

Comment: Hope you see this. My first attempt had a flaw :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It got a bit complicated, but here goes:

```
SELECT IF(MONTH(DATE_ADD('2010-07-02', INTERVAL 28 DAY)) = MONTH('2010-07-02'), 
  DATE_ADD('2010-07-02', INTERVAL 35 DAY),
  DATE_ADD('2010-07-02', INTERVAL 28 DAY));
```

Rationale: If you add 4 weeks or 5 weeks, you're still on the same day; since all months are between 28 and 35 days long, if 4 weeks later is still the same month, add another week.

**UPDATE:** Umm, I did not think this through very well - it works for first X in month, but necessarily for 2nd, 3rd... (i.e. 3rd X in month might return a 2nd X next month). Try #2:

```
SELECT IF(
  CEIL(DAY(DATE_ADD('2010-07-02', INTERVAL 35 DAY)) / 7) = CEIL(DAY('2010-07-02') / 7), 
  DATE_ADD('2010-07-02', INTERVAL 35 DAY),
  DATE_ADD('2010-07-02', INTERVAL 28 DAY));
```

Rationale: `CEIL(DAY(x) / 7)` is x's week number. If it's different when you add 5 weeks, then add 4 weeks.

**UPDATE 2:** LOL, I suck today, I should really think before I post... Week is usually defined as Mon-Sun, or Sun-Mon, not as from whatever started the month till 6 days later. To compensate for this:

```
SELECT IF(
    CEIL((DAY(DATE_ADD('2010-07-02', INTERVAL 28 DAY)) - DAYOFWEEK('2010-07-02')) / 7)
    = CEIL((DAY('2010-07-02') - DAYOFWEEK('2010-07-02')) / 7), 
  DATE_ADD('2010-07-02', INTERVAL 28 DAY),
  DATE_ADD('2010-07-02', INTERVAL 35 DAY));
```

Comment: Ahh, right.  I completely overlooked that as well.  I appreciate the follow-up.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Yeah, no problem. I really hope there will be no 4th one :D

Comment: Update 2 doesn't quite work either.  The second "week number" is zero (the statement in the CEIL() is negative).  An example of something failing: 2010-07-06 goes to 2010-08-10.  2010-07-06 lies on the first Tuesday of the month.  2010-08-10 lies on the second Tuesday of the month.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do the trick?

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(
            DATE_SUB(
                DATE_ADD('2010-07-06', INTERVAL 1 MONTH),

                INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(DATE_ADD('2010-07-06', INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) DAY
            ),

            INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK('2010-07-06') DAY
        )
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for something like June 1, 2010, but after I added code to add 7 days if the month retrieved is in the same month as the start month, things seem to work out better.  So far :p